# How to extract an element from a list within a function

Tags: r

I am trying to extract an element from a list within a function.

````
```{r}
Q7.4<-function (v1,v2){
  mean<-mean(v1)
  median<-median(v1)
  variance<-var(v1)
  minimum<-min(v1)
  maximum<-max(v1)
  Coefficientofvariation<-sqrt(variance)/mean
  my.list<<-list(mean=mean,meadian=median,variance=variance,minimum=minimum,maximum=maximum,Coefficientofvariation=Coefficientofvariation)
  my.list$v2
}
````

When i run the code

```
Q7.4(1:100,mean)
```

I get NULL. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` would try to look for a `list` name `v2`.  Instead, convert the unquoted input to string with `substitute/deparse` and use `[[`

```
Q7.4<-function (v1,v2){
     mean <- mean(v1)
     median <- median(v1)
     variance <- var(v1)
     minimum <- min(v1)
     maximum <- max(v1)
     Coefficientofvariation <- sqrt(variance)/mean
     my.list <- list(mean = mean,
                    median = median,
                    variance = variance,
                    minimum = minimum,
                    maximum = maximum,
                    Coefficientofvariation = Coefficientofvariation)
     my.list[[deparse(substitute(v2))]]
   }
```

-testing

```
Q7.4(1:100, mean)
#[1] 50.5
```

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense. Could you just explain what deparse and substitute is doing?

Comment: Fabulous answer! Learn a lot from you everyday! Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @akrun is excellent. Here is a complementary one.

We can use `eval` + `substitute` to replace `my.list$v2` in your code, i.e.,

```
eval(substitute(v2), my.list)
```

Comment: That is a great way.